# Using VBS to launch multipule IE tabs and populating with username and org

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I have pieced together this bit of code from other places and it works as far as opening tabs and placing the logon info the first tab.   The problem is that it overwrites the first tab with all the logon info of the follow on tabs openings.  Only the first tab receives the logon info.   How can I make this send logon info to each tab as I have it in the VBS?

```
const navOpenInNewTab = &h0800
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
IE.Navigate "https://testurl.com"
IE.Visible = True 
Wscript.Sleep 2000 
ie.Document.getElementById("organization").value = "MyOrg1"
ie.Document.getElementById("userName").value = "esmith1"

IE.Navigate "https://testural.com",CLng(navOpenInNewTab) 
ie.Document.getElementById("organization").value = "MyOrg2"
ie.Document.getElementById("userName").value = "esmith2"
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://testural.com",CLng(navOpenInNewTab) 
ie.Document.getElementById("organization").value = "MyOrg3"
ie.Document.getElementById("userName").value = "esmith3"
IE.Visible = True
```

When the code completes today the first tab has MyOrg3 and esmith3.   The other tabs are blank.

Comment: Automated logins are usually achieved with server side code (sniff for a token in the site cookie on session_start()) and "keep me logged in" options on the login screen OR with IE's built-in form filling or third-party form filling addons. Normally one would set a homepage group of urls, and with persistant credential validation, IE would open each url automatically at the last page the user visited at that site.

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133(v=vs.85).aspx

**Note**    New tabs are opened asynchronously; this method returns as soon as the tab is created, which can be before navigation in the new tab has started. The IWebBrowser2 interface for the destination tab is not available to the caller. Tab order is not guaranteed, especially if this method is called many times quickly in a row.

When navOpenInNewWindow or navOpenInNewTab is specified, **the caller does not receive a pointer to the IWebBrowser2 interface for the new window, so there is no immediate way to manipulate it.**